# Visual Studio macro to find a string and delete matching lines

Tags: visual-studio, macros, replace

In my Visual Studio (2010 C#) solution, I need to delete all lines of code that contain a matching string pattern.

For example, I want to delete all lines that contain ".BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;". The Find and Replace feature of Visual Studio isn't good enough, because you cannot tell it to wipe out the matching lines.

So I think I would need a macro for that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to be a VS solution? A product like text pad can pretty easily look through all the CS files in a folder and do the required replacement

Comment: No it does not need to be a VS macro, though that would be preferred. Can you walk me through how to do it in TextPad? I can do "Find in Files" (just like I can in VS), but I still can't find a way to automate the deletion of the resulting lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tend to create macros in VS by running the macro recorder then editing the resulting code.

So, manually search for the pattern, and press F3. Stop the macro then (or press the line-start key, select to end of line, press delete and then stop the macro).

Edit the macro, the command to delete a line is:

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Delete()
```

You can set the find text with FindText:

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.FindText(".BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsFromStart)
```

Comment: Can you tell us where to enable this Macro recorder?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan in VS2010, its off the tools menu. IIRC they were dropped from VS in 2012, but then returned [as a git add-on](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)

Answer (score 53):

You can use the "Find and Replace" feature of Visual Studio to delete matching lines.

The key is to match the whole line including the end of line character as well. You can do this in wildcard or regular expression mode. In wildcard mode, begin the expression with `*` and end the expression with `*\n`. The asterisks will match any number of characters, and the `\n` will match the end of line character.

In your case, your find query would be "`*.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;*\n`". The replace field should then be left blank.

---

To enable wildcard mode, select 'Wildcards' in the 'Use:' field of the 'Find options' section of the 'Find and Replace' dialog.

[image: Example showing how to turn on wildcard mode]

Comment: And this one actually works in recent versions of Visual Studio, since macros were removed.

Comment: I'm using VS15 and there wasn't a "Use:" checkbox. To get this to work, I needed to check the "Use Regular Expressions" checkbox and my wildcard needed to be **.*** instead of * and **[\n]** instead of **\n**.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! Why would you make it wiki?

Comment: Unfortunately, the  "use" drop down list under "Find Options"  is not available in VS 2017 :( , I'm using VS 2017 professional

Comment: @AnasGhanem see eeScott's comment here. VS15 and VS17 should both have the same options

Answer (score 26):

With Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, 2022 this worked for me. Open Search window, check the "use regular expressions" checkmark. Fill "find what" with

```
.*myCodeFragmentHere.*\r?\n
```

fill "replace" with an empty string.

Remove all regexp (brackets, dots) from the code fragment in your search expression.

Comment: This doesn't delete the line.  This leaves you with an empty line.  Big difference.

Comment: Yes, this would be a show stopper for me, too. But it did not left an empty line...

Comment: You don't need the Carriage Return character.  It works fine as follows (even on Windows, and it deletes the line):  .*myCodeHere.*\n

Comment: This didn't work for me, it found 0 results when trying to get rid of ".*[OperationContract].*\n", maybe the braces break it? If I check the box for "Use Regular Expressions" then it literally removes the entire contents of every file in my solution, not good....

Answer (score 8):

Building upon @HolgerJeromin's answer: instead of guessing the right indentation match (could be tabs could be spaces could be more or less), I prefer matching the beginning of the line using the `^\s*` pattern.

For example, to remove all lines having a `ProducesResponseType` attribute, I use

```
^\s*\[ProducesResponseType.*\n
```

(works on Windows too using VS 2019).

Comment: As a reminder. If there are `(` o `[` you have to escape them using \, e.g. \\(, Otherwise, the regular expression could be bad constructed or simply, it cannot find the string.

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2015 (in which there are no macros and no wildcards), I did the following:

- Open **Find and Replace** (Ctrl+H)
- Set to use Regular Expressions (Alt+E)
- Set the Find box to

> ({line of code string})\r?\n({next line tabbing})

- Leave the Replace box empty
- Replace

Where-

**{line of code string}** = the line of code you wish to remove. Note you need to escape characters such as parenthesis and quotes with a backward slash ()

**{next line tabbing}** = the number of spaces preceding the next line of code (without this your line will be removed but the next line would have double the spaces before it

For example, to remove

> DoSomething("hello");

From -

```
class A
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        DoSomething("hello");
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Replace the following

> (DoSomething(\"hello\")\;)\r?\n({           })

Comment: VS2013 has no Wildcards nor Macros and this never finds "[MyAttribute]". I tried: ([MyAttribute])\r?\n({}), ([MyAttribute])\r?\n({ }), ([MyAttribute])\r\n({ }), ([MyAttribute])\n({ }), (\[MyAttribute\])\r?\n({ }). Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I've found it: FindWhat="\[MyAttribute\]\r\n        " without quotes. ReplaceWith="\r\n" without quotes. UseRegluarExpressions=true.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to remove an attribute ([OperationContract] in my case) and none of the other answers worked for me. I finally got it to work by using the following:

`\[OperationContract\]\r\n\t\t` (Use Regular Expressions)